# Using Reflection to Get All Static Properties in a Class As Objects VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, reflection

I would like to start that I don't want a to hear about how expensive and terrible reflection is. That won't help—I have a very good reason to use reflection and that's not my question.

Specifically, I have a class within a class that contains several static properties of the same type.

```
Public Class Foo
    Public Class Bar
        Public Shared Property prop1 As New CustomClass()
        Public Shared Property prop2 As New CustomClass()
        Public Shared Property prop3 As New CustomClass()
    End Class
End Class

Public Class CustomClass
    Public Sub DoStuff()
    End Sub
End Class
```

I'm looking to create a method in Foo that calls `DoStuff` on each of the properties contained within it. How can I do this? Here's the general idea of what I want to include in Foo, but I obviously can't convert `PropertyInfo` to `CustomClass`:

```
Private Sub Example()
    For Each prop As PropertyInfo In GetType(Foo.Bar).GetProperties()
        DirectCast(prop, CustomClass).DoStuff()
    Next
End Sub
```

How can I get the static properties and cast them to `CustomClass` objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PropertyInfo` represents the type's property get/set method pair. To evaluate the getter you simply call `GetValue`, like so:

(in C# because I'm a language snob)

```cs
foreach( PropertyInfo pi in typeof(Foo.Bar).GetProperties() ) {

    // Use null as arguments because it's a static property without an indexer.
    Object got = pi.GetValue( null, null ); 
    CustomClass got2 = got as CustomClass;
    if( got2 != null ) {
        Console.WriteLine( got2.ToString() );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

And to convert Dai's answer to VB because I'm not a language snob:

```vb
For Each pi As System.Reflection.PropertyInfo in Foo.Bar.GetType.GetProperties()
    ' Use nothing as arguments because it's a shared property without an indexer.
    Dim got = pi.GetValue(Nothing, Nothing)
    Dim got2 as CustomClass = DirectCast(got, CustomClass)
    If Not IsNothing(got2) Then Console.WriteLine(got2.toString())
Next
```

huzzah for less lines and more keystrokes...